# Single force index throwing error on joined table

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to use a left join to bridge two tables and force index an index that only exists on the joined table, but I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FORCE INDEX (l.sfdcId) WHERE l.sfdcId = '003A000001eR0HsIAK'
>   ORDER BY a.activity' at line 3

Here's an output of the query being run (works fine if I remove the FORCE INDEX):

```
SELECT a.activityDate,a.primaryAttributeValue,a.attributeDescription,l.firstName,l.lastName,l.title,l.email
FROM activities AS a LEFT JOIN
     leads AS l 
     ON a.leadId = l.leadId FORCE INDEX (l.sfdcId) 
WHERE l.sfdcId = '003A000001eR0HsIAK'
ORDER BY a.activityDate DESC
```

Any idea why this would fail?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html - *"It is syntactically valid to omit index_list for USE INDEX, which means “use no indexes.” Omitting index_list for FORCE INDEX or IGNORE INDEX is a syntax error."* --- *"The FORCE INDEX hint acts like USE INDEX (index_list), with the addition that a table scan is assumed to be very expensive. In other words, a table scan is used only if there is no way to use one of the named indexes to find rows in the table."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FORCE INDEX` goes after the table definition:

```
SELECT a.activityDate,a.primaryAttributeValue,a.attributeDescription,
       l.firstName,l.lastName,l.title,l .email
FROM activities a LEFT JOIN
     leads l FORCE INDEX (sfdcId)
     ON a.leadId = l.leadId 
WHERE l.sfdcId = '003A000001eR0HsIAK'
ORDER BY a.activityDate DESC ;
```